# SQL - Distinct subquery

Tags: sql, select, subquery, distinct

Someone can explain how to do this query:

i must select all the fields with no duplicate "idPrdodotto"

[image: That's the table]

That's my not working query:

```
SELECT *
FROM riempie1
WHERE idProdotto IN (SELECT DISTINCT idProdotto
                     FROM riempie1
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks all for the replies <3 I solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to be learning SQL, so I'll be a bit verbose.

The `SELECT DISTINCT` in the `IN` subquery does nothing.  Nothing at all.  The `IN` implicitly does a `SELECT DISTINCT` because if something is in `(1, 2, 3)`, then that something is in `(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)`.

What you want to do is to count the number of times that `idProdotto` appears in the table.  You want the `idProdotto` values that only appear once.

A typical approach would use `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(*)` and `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this :

```
SELECT riempie1.* FROM riempie1
join (select idProdotto from riempie1 group by riempie1 having count(riempie1)=1) riempie2
on riempie1.idProdotto = riempie2.idProdotto
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the distinct in the sub query. Instead of that you can do like this:

```
Select distinct column names,.. from table1 where column name= select statement;
```